# System.Security.SecurityException

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate

I'm developing a web application with VS2008 and NHibernate and I cannot access my database (MSSQL Server 2005). 
Here is my stack trace

> **[SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlClientPermission, System.Data,
>   Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
>   failed.]**    System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.Check(Object
>   demand, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean isPermSet) +0
>   System.Security.PermissionSet.Demand() +76
>   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.DemandPermission() +79
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory) +6265031
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +258
>   NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider.GetConnection() +224
>   NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl.SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.Prepare()
>   +30    NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaMetadataUpdater.GetReservedWords(Dialect
>   dialect, IConnectionHelper connectionHelper) +78
>   NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaMetadataUpdater.Update(ISessionFactory
>   sessionFactory) +149
>   NHibernate.Impl.SessionFactoryImpl..ctor(Configuration cfg, IMapping
>   mapping, Settings settings, EventListeners listeners) +803
>   NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.BuildSessionFactory() +129
>   DALC.Contest.save() +128

Comment: And your security settings  are?

Answer (score 0):

Without a bit more information this sounds like a AppDomain Security issue. Here are a few links. The first is probably the one that will help you the most:

[System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlClientPermission, System.Data](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlnetfx/thread/1505d7e6-59dc-4997-b707-9e9736a1f978)

[How to provide extra trust for an Internet Explorer hosted assembly](http://blogs.msdn.com/shawnfa/archive/2003/06/26/57026.aspx)

[.NET Framework Enterprise Security Policy Administration and Deployment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302354.aspx)